Minimization of KL divergence is equivalent to minimization of NLL using Dirac
I am reading "Probabilistic Machine Learning: An Introduction", In chapter 4 Statistics page 109:
A empirical distribution
$$p_D(y) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\delta(y-y_n)$$
The KL divergence
$$\begin{align}
D_{KL}(p_D(y)||p(y|\theta)) &= \sum_y[p_D\log p_D - p_D\log p(y|\theta)]\\
&= -H(p_D)-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \log p(y_n|\theta)
\end{align}$$
I don't understand the second term in the last equations from my understanding
I tried to derive the second term but ended up with extra term $\delta(y_n-y_n)$ which is infinity
$$\begin{align}
p_D \log p(y|\theta) &= \sum_y \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\delta(y-y_n)\log p(y|\theta)\\
                   &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_y \delta(y-y_n)\log p(y|\theta)\\
                   &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \delta(y_n-y_n)\log p(y_n|\theta)\\
\end{align}$$
I am wondering how the equations in the textbook are derived or the delta term is handled, step by step with explanations.
